# What's this after aggregation in django?

Tags: python, django, aggregation

I see the following code from a django project. I understand it's aggregation, but what's ['kw__sum'] after the aggregation?

```
Project.objects.filter(project = project).aggregate(Sum('kw'))['kw__sum']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here if you look in [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) you will see that [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) returns dictionary so last part is just dict lookup

```
aggregation = Project.objects.filter(project = project).aggregate(Sum('kw'))
result = aggregation['kw__sum']
```

From the docs

> Returns a dictionary of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc.) calculated over the QuerySet. Each argument to aggregate() specifies a value that will be included in the dictionary that is returned.